Add items to the View container in VSCode extension webview
Is there a VSCode API to add actions to the View Container title section, similar to how Github Copilot Chat VSCode extension does? For reference, checkout the highlighted red box in the screenshot, which has a New Chat button, Historical chats, and more options in the dropdown menu.


I believe this has an example of what you want: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#menu-example

If your viewContainer has only one visible view, the commands you added to that view (using the view/title contribution point) will be moved to that location.
The viewContainer itself, on the other hand, does not have an API/contribution point to add commands to it.
Answered in the VS Code Discussions forum (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/2454)
